# How to add Layout as a child

Tags: android, layout, appendchild

In my application I have 2 layouts. One's is root layout that changes dynamically and the second is just a form that opens many times. The form must be child of the root layout but I'm failing to perform so.

I assume that I should simply use:

> main.AddView(formLayout)

but I can't figure out how get this formLayout object.

Will thank you for possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the advice of cjk I wrote piece of code that actually answers my question:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
main = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content));
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup form=  (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.formLayout, null);
main.addView(form);
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the `LayoutInflater` object [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

This allows you to create an object from the xml layout in your project.

Comment: Thank you, that was precisely what I sought!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question properly, but something like that might work:

```
View myView;
myView = (View) this.findViewById(R.id.formLayout);
main.addView(myView);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've tried to to but I get null.
I believe the reason is that formLayout wasn't loaded yet (because it's another layout and another XML file).

Answer (score 0):

By get I figure you mean you want to retrieve a field in the new opened layout, you can do it by making it a new Intent and using startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.